# How can I get the week number considering Sunday as the start day?

Tags: php, datetime, week-number

```
$date = 'some date';
$todays_week = date('W',strtotime($date));
```

This code gives me the week number considering Monday as the first day of the week. I want to get the week number considering Sunday as the starting day of week. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is not any option to change the starting day. So, you can check if the current day is Sunday and if so, increment the week number with 1:

```
function getIsoWeeksInYear($year) {
    $date = new DateTime;
    $date->setISODate($year, 53);
    return ($date->format("W") === "53" ? 53 : 52);
}

function getWeek($date) {
    $week = date('W',strtotime($date));
    $day  = date('N',strtotime($date));
    $max_weeks = getIsoWeeksInYear(date('Y',strtotime($date)));

    if($day == 7 && $week != $max_weeks) {
        return ++$week;
    } elseif($day == 7) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return $week;
    }
}

echo getWeek('2012-12-30');
```

Comment: Not quite. Remember that ISO 8601 week numbers range from 1 - 53 *inclusive*. For example, Sunday, January 3, 2010 is ISO year 2009, ISO week 53. ["If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00). 28 December is always in the last week of its year."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)

Comment: Thanks for the comment: +1. I wasn't sure about the last week. Changed it to 53 then.

Comment: Not all ISO years have 53 weeks. The number of weeks is *either* 52 or 53, depending on various factors. See [ISO week date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). In short, testing Dec 28 should find the highest week number for the year (52 or 53).

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution is to simply add 1 whole day to the input:

```
$todays_week = date('W', strtotime($date) + 60 * 60 * 24 );
```

The only case that this doesn't work is where it is the 31st of December an it is also a Sunday. In this case, the answer will incorrectly say 1. You'll have to check for this.